# want to merge two column that contains mobile number into one based on the condition that mobile no should be 10 digits

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am new to excel please help me.

So the situation is we have two contact no column

```
contact no      contact no 1
9864573828       0145883
9834765849       1923832
018294           9876547834
```

i want to merge two column into 1 having contact no of 10 digit.

```
contact no      
9864573828       
9834765849       
9876547834
```

I'm using Excel 2013

Comment: Make sure to mention/tag Excel 2013 if you plan to ask more questions. If you don't you end up with lots of answers that work, just not for your version. (Or upgrade your Excel)

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2013 this formula can be used to list the 10 digit numbers from the first and second range without gaps:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A:A)/(LEN(A:A)=10)/(ISNUMBER(--A:A)),ROW(1:1))),INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/(LEN(B:B)=10)/(ISNUMBER(--B:B)),ROW(1:1)-SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A:A)=10)*(ISNUMBER(--A:A)))))),"")
```

It uses a lot of resources to calculate, so whole column references is highly discouraged. So use actual ranges instead like:

```
=IFERROR(
   IFERROR(
     INDEX(A:A,
           AGGREGATE(15,6,
                     ROW($A$2:$A$5)
                     /(LEN($A$2:$A$5)=10)
                     /(ISNUMBER(--$A$2:$A$5)),
                     ROW(1:1))),
     INDEX(B:B,
           AGGREGATE(15,6,
                     ROW($B$2:$B$5)
                     /(LEN($B$2:$B$5)=10)
                     /(ISNUMBER(--$B$2:$B$5)),
                     ROW(1:1)
                     -SUMPRODUCT(
                         (LEN($A$2:$A$5)=10)
                         *(ISNUMBER(--$A$2:$A$5)))))),
   "")
```

Note: I think (unable to verify myself) the formula needs entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` to make it an array formula.

[image]

What this formula does is get the first row of the first range where the string length is 10 and the string converted to a number does not produce an error (what would happen in case of text characters in the string).

When you drag down the formula it shows the second found, third, etc... until no values are found in the first range anymore.

In that case the IFERROR makes it look for the same logic in the second range.

As we want it to show the first found value first, we can't reset the `ROW(1:1)` * - that is used as a counter for the first smallest, second smallest, etc.. - * therefore we use the same counter and use SUMPRODUCT to subtract the total number of strings meeting the conditions in the first range. That way the counter will start at 1 for the second range and starts counting from there.

If no more values are found in the second range it will show a blank value.
So you can drag down the formula up to the first blank result to show each result.

It's probably still slow with actual range references. I highly advise to upgrade to Office 365.

Comment: (hooray for Office 365. I forgot how complicated it was in the past)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula-

```
=LET(x,TOCOL(A2:B13,1),FILTER(x,LEN(x)=10))
```

[image]

Comment: Sir it is saying invalid function. Why there is b13 in  tocol(a2,b13,1)

Comment: @BibekKarna You can increase/decrease range in `TOCOL()` function. If you add more data then tocol will automatically include that in result. `1` is for ignoring blanks. What is your excel version. I think your version of excel doesn't support `TOCOL()`.

Comment: my excel version is 2013

Comment: Then this formula will not work. You need some `VBA` codes.

Answer (score 0):

Since your excel version doesn't support `TOCOL()` and some other formulas you can use this simple solution:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)=10,A2,IF(LEN(B2)=10,B2,""))
```

Put it in `C2` and drag id down for a result:
[image]

Since you didn't specify what to do if both columns has 10 digit number or both doesn't, in those cases it will return first 10 digit number or empty string.

Comment: if  want both digit no then what will be the formula